# Hibernate Delete Operation not updating MySql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

My delete operation is not deleting recode in database.

My entity classes :

```
    @Entity  
@Table(name= "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;  
    private String userName,password,type,fullName; 

    public int getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  
    public void setId(int id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  

    public String getFullName() {  
        return fullName;  
    }  
    public void setFullName(String fName) {  
        this.fullName = fName;  
    }

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    public String getUserName() {  
        return userName;  
    }  
    public void setUserName(String userName) {  
        this.userName = userName;  
    }  
    public String getPassword() {  
        return password;  
    }  
    public void setPassword(String password) {  
        this.password = password;  
    }     
    public String getType() {  
        return type;  
    }  
    public void setType(String type) {  
        this.type = type;  
    }     



}

    @Entity  
@Table(name= "Cart")
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id; 
    private String userName;    
    private String itemSkus;
    private String itemsQuantity;


    public int getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  
    public void setId(int id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    } 

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    public String getUserName() {  
        return userName;  
    }  
    public void setUserName(String uName) {  
        this.userName = uName;  
    }

    public String getItems(){
        return this.itemSkus;
    }

    public void setItems(String items){
        this.itemSkus=items;
    }


    public String getItemsQuantity(){
        return this.itemsQuantity;
    }

    public void setItemsQuantity(String itemsQ){
        this.itemsQuantity=itemsQ;
    }



}
```

The DAO class method is for cart is as below:

```
public int deleteCart(String userID){
    Session currentSession=sessionObject.getSession();
    //String query="from Cart Where  userName :uName";
    String query="DELETE FROM Cart where userName = :uName";

    Query queryResult = currentSession.createQuery(query);
    queryResult.setParameter("uName", userID);

    int result = queryResult.executeUpdate();

    System.out.println("Cart delete result "+result); 

    return result;
}
```

I tried running query in MySQL workbench and table updated nicely. Only with hibernate its not updating.

I end up having number of results in update query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the quesry inside a transaction, `begin` it, `execute the delete query` and finally `commit` the transaction and `rollback` it when an error or exception occured:

```
public int deleteCart(String userID){

    Session currentSession=sessionObject.getSession();
    Transaction tr= currentSession.beginTransaction();
    //String query="from Cart Where  userName :uName";
  try{
    String query="DELETE FROM Cart where userName = :uName";

    Query queryResult = currentSession.createQuery(query);
    queryResult.setParameter("uName", userID);

    int result = queryResult.executeUpdate();
    tr.commit();

    System.out.println("Cart delete result "+result); 

    return result;
  } catch (Exception ex) {
       tr.rollback();
       return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your session needs to be flushed.  Add this line before you **prinltln** like this.

```
currentSession.flush();
System.out.println("Cart delete result "+result);
```

Comment: question owner says:_with hibernate its not updating._  notice: `flush()` will sync the database with the current state of object/objects held in the memory but `it does not commit the transaction`(depends on flash mode). but `commit()` will update the database permanent. he can use the flash after updating and any time he want

Comment: Farhang Amary 'Ferhęg'.  Hibernate's default mode will flush on:
+before some query executions, +from org.hibernate.Transaction.commit()
+from Session.flush()
This answers the owner's question - "hibernate its not updating"

Reference:http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing

Comment: Great, so read the link carefully and do some tests then you'll get this result: `when tr.commit() is called in the default FlushMode , currentSession.flush() will be executed implicitly before execution of tr.commit().` good luck.